# foreign key not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to establish a relationship between two tables using phpMyAdmin. But I am having some trouble of doing this.

I have the foreign key set up but for some reason it dos not add the id of the other table. I am very new to MySQL and can't figure this one out.

Here is my table structure:

**tblanswers**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblanswers` (
  `answerid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answerA` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `answerB` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `answerC` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`answerid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cid` (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=210 ;
```

**credentials**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `credentials` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `second_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `cid` (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=106 ;
```

I am very unclear how to set foreign keys and how they are connect the tables I looked up couple of tutorials but they did not really explain much in detail.

Comment: how are the tables connected with each other?

Comment: with a foreign key i have a cid as a foreign key in tblanswers

Comment: now that i look at them i dount think i set them right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this on table `tblanswers`

```
CONSTRAINT tb_FK FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES credentials (cid)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f7d12)

Comment: i tried your advice and added the line to the table you suggested but it still dose not add the value of cid when data is inserted from credentials to cid in tblanswers do u have any other advice ?

Comment: if you mean he values are not inserted on the other table. it's normal, you need to have to inserts on this.

Comment: how do i make the inserts on this ?